# Add new line after a string match in JSON file

Tags: sed, json

I need a help doing the below task.

In a JSON file I have a part something like below

```json
"Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::12345677890:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::12345677891:root",
```

where in I need to find a string "AWS": [ and it should add a new line with "arn:aws:iam::33333333333:root", so the updated
json content should look like this.

```json
"Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::33333333333:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::12345677890:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::12345677891:root",
```

How to do this with sed?

Comment: You should use `jq`

Comment: Don't. Don't use sed. Don't think in lines. This is not how JSON is structured.

Comment: If you can't install `jq`, `perl` >= version 5.14 includes a JSON parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Principal` is a top-level object in your JSON document and that you want to add some string, kept in the shell variable `entry`, to the (start of the) `AWS` array beneath that:

```bsh
entry='arn:aws:iam::33333333333:root'

jq --arg e "$entry" '.Principal.AWS |= [$e,.[]]' file.json
```

The `jq` expression adds the string, which is kept in the `jq` variable `$e`, assigned on the command line using `--arg`, to the start of the array `AWS` using `|=` (it updates/rewrites the array with a new array, had from the added element `$e` followed by the elements of the original array).

Adding the element to the *end* of the array would be ever so slightly easier, and possibly more efficient (as the whole array does not need to be rewritten), with

```bsh
jq --arg e "$entry" '.Principal.AWS += [$e]' file.json
```

Testing:

```bsh
$ cat file.json
{
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
      "arn:aws:iam::12345677890:root",
      "arn:aws:iam::12345677891:root"
    ]
  }
}
```

```bsh
$ entry='arn:aws:iam::33333333333:root'
$ jq --arg e "$entry" '.Principal.AWS |= [$e,.[]]' file.json
{
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
      "arn:aws:iam::33333333333:root",
      "arn:aws:iam::12345677890:root",
      "arn:aws:iam::12345677891:root"
    ]
  }
}
```

```bsh
$ jq --arg e "$entry" '.Principal.AWS += [$e]' file.json
{
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
      "arn:aws:iam::12345677890:root",
      "arn:aws:iam::12345677891:root",
      "arn:aws:iam::33333333333:root"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't provide the complete json format Initially sorry for that.
</code>
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [ 
   </code>
As Principal is not the top level object here. What changes I need to make. Could you please help me

Comment: @Creative Your `Statement` is an array. If you wish to affect the first element of that array, use `.Statement[0].Principal.AWS` in place of `. Principal.AWS`.  If you want me to update my answer, then you would need to clarify your question, adding the more complete document.

Comment: I wanted add in the all elements. .Statement[].Principal.AWS  worked. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is the wrong tool here – [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) and hence, a tool that can apply regular expressions won't be able to parse all valid JSON.

So, use a tool designed to parse and modify JSON instead – `jq` is great, but often, writing (literally) 7 lines of python is clearer for the occasional user.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# You'll want to save this to a file, e.g. mypythonscript,
# and make it executable: chmod 755 mypythonscript
import json, sys
data_in = None
with open(sys.argv[1]) as infile:
  data_in = json.load(infile)
data_in["AWS"] = ["arn:aws:iam::33333333333:root"] + data_in["AWS"]
with open(sys.argv[1], "w") as outfile:
  json.dump(data_in, outfile)
```

would allow you to just

```bsh
./mypythonscript data.json
```

Comment: Doesn't `json.load()` need an argument in the parentheses?

Comment: @Cyrus ah sorry, just saw what you mean, fixed it. Thanks!