# Write sed command to input file

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression, json

I'm building a script to automate boilerplate. In it, I append a string:

```
"compile": "browserify js/main.js > ./dist/bundle.js -t babelify",
"watch": "watchify js/*.js -o ./dist/bundle.js -d",
```

With sed, I find the string **"scripts"** and append, as such.

```
sed '/"scripts"/a "compile": "browserify js/main.js > ./dist/bundle.js -t babelify",\n "watch": "watchify js/*.js -o ./dist/bundle.js -d",' package.json
```

So, the command has the syntax:

```bsh
sed '/pattern/a' input
```

My problem is that this command is not mutating the input file, nor can I write the output to a file, e.g.,

```bsh
sed '/pattern/a' input > output.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**GOAL:**

Input file (`package.json`):

```
{
  "name": "torrent-search-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "torrent-search-api": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.8",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "browserify": "^17.0.0"
  }
}
```

```bsh
$ <command> package.json
```

Output:

```bsh
cat package.json
```

```bsh
{
  "name": "torrent-search-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "browserify js/main.js > ./dist/bundle.js -t babelify",
    "watch": "watchify js/*.js -o ./dist/bundle.js -d",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "torrent-search-api": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.8",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "browserify": "^17.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add new line after a string match in JSON file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685561/add-new-line-after-a-string-match-in-json-file)

Comment: as my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685561/add-new-line-after-a-string-match-in-json-file/685567#685567) points out: `sed` is simply the **wrong tool** for the job, as JSON is *not* a regular language. So, drop sed and use a JSON tool. `jq` is popular.

Answer (score 0):

To add a single key-value pair to the `scripts` object:

```bsh
jq --arg key 'compile' --arg value 'browserify js/main.js > ./dist/bundle.js -t babelify' \
    '.scripts += { ($key): $value }' file
```

Adding two keys and values, just pipe the output through exactly the same `jq` expression again, but with other values for the internal `$key` and `$value` variables:

```bsh
jq --arg key 'compile' --arg value 'browserify js/main.js > ./dist/bundle.js -t babelify' \
    '.scripts += { ($key): $value }' file |
jq --arg key 'watch' --arg value 'watchify js/*.js -o ./dist/bundle.js -d' \
    '.scripts += { ($key): $value }'
```

Given the document in the question, this would produce

```json
{
  "name": "torrent-search-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "compile": "browserify js/main.js > ./dist/bundle.js -t babelify",
    "watch": "watchify js/*.js -o ./dist/bundle.js -d"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "torrent-search-api": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.8",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "browserify": "^17.0.0"
  }
}
```

You would redirect the output of the second `jq` command to a new file and then move that file to the old name, like one usually does.

You could obviously do both operations in one go if you know about `$ARGS.named`, an object containing the named variables on the command line:

```bsh
jq --arg compile 'browserify js/main.js > ./dist/bundle.js -t babelify' \
   --arg watch   'watchify js/*.js -o ./dist/bundle.js -d' \
   '.scripts += $ARGS.named' file
```

The result is the same as with the pipeline using the two more naive commands, and depending on your script and other circumstances, you would either want to do it that way, or like show just above.